# Get Strings used in Java from JNI

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

### *JAVA Code*

Here is some part of my code that I have written in ***JAVA***, As you can see this is a class called `JC_VerificationCandidate` that have two `String` members `enrollmentID` and `seedIndex`.

```
class JC_VerificationCandidate {

    public JCDSM_VerificationCandidate( String enrollmentID, String seedIndex ) {
        this.enrollmentID = enrollmentID;
        this.seedIndex    = seedIndex;
    }

    public String enrollmentID;
    public String seedIndex;
}
```

Here is main class where I have native method and from where I called that native method.

```
public class DsmLibraryTest extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        JCDSM_VerificationCandidate verificationCandidate[] = {new JCDSM_VerificationCandidate( "tom", "anna" )}; 
        dsm.JDSMVerify( 123456, "http:\\www.test_url.com", bytes, verificationCandidate );

    }

    public native int JDSMVerify(
                   int                         someValue1,
                   String                      someValue2,
                   byte[]                      someValue3,
                   JC_VerificationCandidate    jVerificationCandList[] );
}
```

As you can see I create array with one object and give it to my function.

```
JCDSM_VerificationCandidate verificationCandidate[] = {new JCDSM_VerificationCandidate( "tom", "anna" )};
```

### *JNI Code*

***How can I get that two strings `enrollmentID`, `eedIndex` that I have set from java application and which are stored in `jVerificationCandList` ?***

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_Dsm_Test_DSM_JDSMVerify( JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint jhDevice, jstring jurlID,
                                                         jbyteArray jInputInfo, jobjectArray jVerificationCandList ) {


}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following code should allow you to access the field **enrollmentID**. Use the [JNI String functions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#string_operations) to read/manipulate them.

```
// Load the class
jclass jclass_JCV = env->FindClass(env, "my.package.JC_VerificationCandidate");

jfieldID fid_enrollmentID = env->GetFieldID(env, jclass_JCV, "enrollmentID" , "Ljava/lang/String;");

// Access the first element in the jVerificationCandList array 
jobject jc_v = env->GetObjectArrayElement(env, jVerificationCandList, 0);

// get reference to the string 
jstring jstr = (jstring) env->GetObjectField(env, jc_v, enrollmentID);

// Convert jstring to native string
const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, 0);
```

Comment: const char *nativeString = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jstr, 0); Okay !!! Thats All !!

Comment: Don't forget to release it later, else you will leak.
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(...)