# How to handle struct-like jobject in JNI

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

I have a question using the Java Native Interface. I've the following class:

```
public class TestJNI {
  public static native long sendCommand(int id, MyParms param);

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("TestNative");
  }
}
```

MyParams looks like this:

```
public class MyParams {
  public String lpstrElementName;
}
```

And then I have a C file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "TestJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_TestJNI_sendCommand
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint id, jobject param)
{
  // code
}
```

What I don't know at this point is how to handle the jobject parameter and how I can access my element name attribute?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. I suggest you first have a look at the [JNI documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/index.html) specifically [Accessing Fields of Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jni/functions.html#accessing-fields-of-objects)

Comment: I can't believe that it isn't marked as dup..

Answer (score 1):

This is a short example for accessing an integer class field, for more information use the links [Jorn Vernee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3699139/jorn-vernee) already posted.

```
class MyParms
{
  int myVar;
}
```

Function for reading the value of *myVar*:

```
JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_TestJNI_sendCommand
  (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jint id, jobject param)
{
  jfieldID jfid;
  jclass jclass;
  jint val;

  jclass = (*env)->GetObjectClass( env, param );
  jfid   = (*env)->GetFieldID( env, jclass, "myVar", "I");
  val    = (*env)->GetIntField( env, param, jfid );
}
```

Edit: For accessing a string field...

```
env->GetFieldID( clazz, "myVar", "Ljava/lang/String;" );
```

For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343459/get-strings-used-in-java-from-jni#6343805) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327773/android-jni-get-two-fields-from-java-class).