# Is it possible to reliably modify a java string inside the C++ NDK directly (without making a copy)?

Tags: android, string, android-ndk

The only way I see to do it is getting a reference to do `jstring` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343805/4829166), then `GetStringCritical`, and using it as a `u16string` (so any other strings acting upon it should be `u16string` as well).

But I'm not sure that will work since it doesn't seem certain that `GetStringCritical` will return a pointer to the original (it's possible it will create a copy).

The posts I found about this are relatively old, I'm wondering whether there is a better way to do this, or maybe now all modern platforms do not create a copy when using `GetStringCritical`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in Java are immutable by design.  They can't change, and finding some hack to do so via C would probably break things if possible.

Comment: Oh yeah... dunno why I forgot that.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to use a C++ char* as a string inside java?

Comment: No, but it is possible to create a new java string object in C++ that java can then use